# I have to click on my link twice before state is update and styling is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink, react-router-dom

i have an issue. I want the styling of my Link to change based on a state. But the issue is that, i have to click on the link twice before the styling is updated. But when i use the e.prevetndefault, the styling is applied when i click the link but I cannot go to the page.  Here is the code.

```
function Footer(){
    
    const [activeValue, setIsActive] =  useState("0")
    

    return(
        <div className="footer">
    <ul className="socials">
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>       </a></li>
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fab fa-instagram"></i>        </a></li>
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fab fa-twitter"></i>          </a></li>
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fas fa-podcast"></i>          </a></li>
        <li></li>
        

        <li><Link to="/peepNews"    onClick={()=>{setIsActive("1")}}        style={activeValue=="1"?{color:"#0B77BE",fontWeight:"600"}:null}    >Peep News</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/faq"         onClick={()=>{setIsActive("2")}}         style={activeValue=="2"?{color:"#0B77BE",fontWeight:"600"}:null}   >FAQ</Link></li>
        <li><a href="" style={{color:"gray", fontWeight:"200"}}>Careers</a></li>
        <li><Link to="/legal"       onClick={()=>{setIsActive("3")}}         style={activeValue=="3"?{color:"#0B77BE",fontWeight:"600"}:null}       >Legal</Link></li>
        <li><a href="https://jupeglobal.com/venture-capital/">Jupe Global   </a></li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
       
    );
}
```

EDIT:
This is when i added the useEffect hook. But the issue is that whenever the page re-render, the activeValue is set back to the default Value(0) instead of 1,2,3 etc.

```
function Footer(){
    
    const [activeValue, setIsActive] =  useState("0")
    
    useEffect(() => { 
        
            setIsActive(activeValue)  ;
            alert(activeValue);
            
    
         
     },[activeValue])

    

    return(
        <div className="footer">
    <ul className="socials">
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>       </a></li>
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fab fa-instagram"></i>        </a></li>
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fab fa-twitter"></i>          </a></li>
        <li><a href="">     <i className="fas fa-podcast"></i>          </a></li>
        <li></li>
        

        <li><Link to="/peepNews"        onClick={()=>{setIsActive("1")}}    style={activeValue=="1"?{color:"#0B77BE",fontWeight:"600"}:null}    >Peep News</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/faq"         onClick={()=>{setIsActive("2")}}         style={activeValue=="2"?{color:"#0B77BE",fontWeight:"600"}:null}   >FAQ</Link></li>
        <li><a href="" style={{color:"gray", fontWeight:"200"}}>Careers</a></li>
        <li><Link to="/legal"       onClick={()=>{setIsActive("3")}}         style={activeValue=="3"?{color:"#0B77BE",fontWeight:"600"}:null}       >Legal</Link></li>
        <li><a href="https://jupeglobal.com/venture-capital/">Jupe Global   </a></li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
       
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With react-router you don't need to use the Link element to navigate to a new page, particularly if you want to functionality to be a little more complex.

You can create a history file and export a history object:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then import history into any file where you would like to navigate using javascript. Then in your file you can simply create a  which you can style as you please (or continue to use  with e.preventDefault()) which then navigates on the click action.

```
  <li>
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setIsActive("1");
        history.push("/peepNews");
      }}
      style={activeValue == "1" ? { color: "#0B77BE", fontWeight: "600" } : undefined} >
      Peep News</div>
  </li>
```

Comment: wow. that surprisingly worked! but there is an issue, all my styling for the footer just went away. it became a really really messy style. i tried to use a Use Effect . I would like you to have a look at the code

Comment: I don't think your useEffect is doing anything since it will only be called on change of activeValue. I would probably use condition CSS rather than inline styles for managing styling. useState should maintain the value between renders so long as you've setup everything correctly.

Comment: hey, it worked. thank you very very much. Have been really really busy. thank you

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Please remember to up vote and / or mark as correct any answers to your questions that have been useful. Thanks